# JWSDP 2.0 installation issues in ubuntu14.04LTS

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

1. First, I executed `./jwsdp-2_0-unix.sh` and got:

   ```
   For help, type './jwsdp-2_0-unix.sh -help'

   Using / var / tmp as temporary directory ...
   Searching for Java (TM) 2 Platform, Standard Edition ...
   tail: Unable to open the "+368" Read data: No such file or directory
   Initializing InstallShield Wizard ...
   Error: Can not find or can not load the main class JWSDP
   ```
2. Next, I executed `export _POSIX2_VERSION=199209` then `./jwsdp-2_0-unix.sh`:

   ```
   For help, type './jwsdp-2_0-unix.sh -help'

   Using /var/tmp as temporary directory...
   Searching for Java(TM) 2 Platform, Standard Edition...
   Initializing InstallShield Wizard...
   The wizard cannot continue because of the following error: could not load  wizard specified in /wizard.inf (104)
   ```
3. Finally, I executed `./jwsdp-2_0-unix.sh -is:debug`:

   ```
   For help, type './jwsdp-2_0-unix.sh -help'

   Using / var / tmp as temporary directory ...
   Searching for Java (TM) 2 Platform, Standard Edition ...
   Initializing InstallShield Wizard ...
   line / col: 0/0

   com.jxml.quick.QPE; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.beans.editors.StringEditor
      at com.jxml.quick.QContext.throwPE (QContext.java:32)
      at com.jxml.quick.QContext.forName (QContext.java:23)
      at com.jxml.quick.tf.QPropertyEditor.setPropertyEditorClassName (QPropertyEditor.java:41)
      at com.jxml.quick.access.QPEClassAccess.add (QPEClassAccess.java:19)
      at com.jxml.quick.tf.QStringTF.add (QStringTF.java:53)
      at com.jxml.quick.engine.QElementFactory $ QElement $ EState.processEnd (QElementFactory.java:284)
      at com.jxml.quick.engine.QCMFactory $ QCM.endElement (QCMFactory.java:112)
      at com.jxml.quick.engine.QContextImpl.endElement (QContextImpl.java:54)
      at com.jxml.quick.QConvert.startElement (QConvert.java:93)
      at com.jxml.quick.cvt.CTargetEditor.cvt (CTargetEditor.java:42)
      at com.jxml.quick.cvt.CAttribute.cvt (CAttribute.java:165)
      at com.jxml.quick.cvt.CElement.cvt (CElement.java:155)
      at com.jxml.quick.cvt.CChild.cvt (CChild.java:63)
      at com.jxml.quick.cvt.CElement.cvt (CElement.java:161)
      at com.jxml.quick.cvt.CQuick.cvt (CQuick.java:53)
      at com.jxml.quick.cvt.CRootBase.eval (CRootBase.java:10)
      at com.jxml.quick.Quick.convert (Quick.java:133)
      at com.jxml.quick.engine.QCMLBindings.getQmlDoc (QCMLBindings.java:21)
      at com.jxml.quick.engine.QCMLBindings.createSchemaContext (QCMLBindings.java:32)
      at com.jxml.quick.engine.QCMLBindings.parseSchema (QCMLBindings.java:60)
      at com.jxml.quick.Quick.parseSchema (Quick.java:213)
      at com.jxml.quick.Quick.parseSchema (Quick.java:196)
      at com.installshield.qjml.QJML.getSchemaDoc (QJML.java:130)
      at com.installshield.qjml.QJML.read (QJML.java:223)
      at com.installshield.qjml.QJML.read (QJML.java:210)
      at com.installshield.wizard.WizardLoader.load (WizardLoader.java:102)
      at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard.loadWizard (Wizard.java:375)
      at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard.main (Wizard.java:153)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
      at run.main (run.java:76)
      at JWSDP.main (JWSDP.java:93)
   QJMLException: (error code = 3002; message = "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.beans.editors.StringEditor")
      at com.installshield.qjml.QJML.read (QJML.java:232)
      at com.installshield.qjml.QJML.read (QJML.java:210)
      at com.installshield.wizard.WizardLoader.load (WizardLoader.java:102)
      at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard.loadWizard (Wizard.java:375)
      at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard.main (Wizard.java:153)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
      at run.main (run.java:76)
      at JWSDP.main (JWSDP.java:93)

   The wizard can not continue because of the following error: could not load wizard specified in /wizard.inf (104)
   ```

If anyone encountered the same problem, please tell me how to fix it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I tried to installed JWSDP on the windows and found it needs jdk1.6. So,I installed the jdk1.6 on my Ubuntu immediately and executed `./jwsdp-2_0-unix.sh -is:javahome /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_45/`. It worked. I attached a screenshot below:

[image]